# Using ANT to copy files via SCP to an Ubuntu server with root disabled (required SUDO)

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ubuntu, scp

I want to copy files from my local development environment (Win7, Eclipse, ANT) to a remote Ubuntu server. Ubuntu sever locks root by default, so all copy commands require `sudo cp ...`.

Is there a way to use ANT to accomplish this easily? I don't see any options for using SUDO, but I'm new to using ANT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install cygwin (cygwin.com) or mingw (mingw.org) and use scp/ssh from there. It's far easier to setup authorization there (you do it in $HOME/.ssh/ as usual) so that you do not have to pass it in the ant script.

Comment: But my local development system is windows, I think you're answer assumes that my dev system *is* the Ubuntu server, no? Or perhaps I don't understand. I don't even have ANT installed on the server.

Comment: I see now. Yeah. Use scp task - that's one of the options - then you would have to setup authorisation (it can be tricky with jsch). Another option (which I prefer) is to install cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/) or mingw (http://www.mingw.org/) and use scp/ssh from there. It's far easier to setup authorization there (you do it in $HOME/.ssh/ as usual) so that you do not have to pass it in the ant script.

Answer (score 1):

When your local develop environment is on Windows you may use the [**Putty Client**](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), a free Telnet/SSH client for Windows.Simply use the commandline tools plink, pscp, .. that Putty provides and use them within the Ant exec task.
see [**Putty Documentation**](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/) for further details
plink => http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink

Answer (score 0):

Use [SCP](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) Task . This has dependency on [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html). I use this to copy files from windows to unix. It could probably copy from unix to windows (if windows is running ssh server)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it will be easy to do it with cygwin/mingw,
but if you want to do everything in pure java, here is an example to exec sudo, 
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java

Answer (score 0):

How about following ant tasks?

```
<scp  todir="{$username}:{$password}@{$host}:/tmp/x" sftp="true">
  <fileset dir="."/>
</scp>
<sshexec host="{$host}" username="{$username}" password="{$password}"
         trust="yes" command="sudo -S -p '' mv /tmp/x /root/x"
         input="/tmp/input"/>
```

, where "/tmp/input" will include the password for "sudo".  If you use ant-1.8.3,
you may want to use "inputstring" attribute.